# How do we use regex filter in jsonpath_ng python, it treats / as SORT Direction. any alternative?

Tags: python, json, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

I'm trying to find the Worker whose Worker Value contains the number 880099 as substring. Here i'm trying to find priyanka's details using her employee ID.

My Code .

```
json_data = json.loads(json_string)
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parser
query = r'$[?(@.Worker =~ /.*?880099.*/i)]'
for match in parser.parse(query).find(json_data):
```

JSON DATA :
[{
"Time Off Entry": "1 Feb, 2021 - 1 Days (Divakar (77877))",
"Worker": "Divakar (77877)",
"Request Type": "Time Off Request",
"Time Off/Absence Table": "IND Annual Time Off",
"Type": "Annual Leave",
"Entered On": 1611187200000,
"Approval Date": 1611187200000,
"Time Off Date": 1612137600000,
"Approved": 1,
"Unit of Time": "Days"
}, {
"Time Off Entry": "1 Feb, 2021 - 1 Days (Priyanka (880099))",
"Worker": "Priyanks (880099)",
"Request Type": "Time Off Request",
"Time Off/Absence Table": "IND Sick/Casual Time Off",
"Type": "Sick/Casual Leave",
"Entered On": 1612310400000,
"Approval Date": 1612310400000,
"Time Off Date": 1612137600000,
"Approved": 1,
"Unit of Time": "Days"
}]

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes works fine. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsonpath-ng syntax for the regex-comparison is not correct. Try quotes around the pattern instead like this:

```
parser.parse('$[?(@.Worker =~ ".*880099.*")]').find(json_data)]
```

Full sample:

```
import json
json_string =  "[{ \"Time Off Entry\": \"1 Feb, 2021 - 1 Days (Divakar (77877))\", \"Worker\": \"Divakar (77877)\", \"Request Type\": \"Time Off Request\", \"Time Off/Absence Table\": \"IND Annual Time Off\", \"Type\": \"Annual Leave\", \"Entered On\": 1611187200000, \"Approval Date\": 1611187200000, \"Time Off Date\": 1612137600000, \"Approved\": 1, \"Unit of Time\": \"Days\" }, { \"Time Off Entry\": \"1 Feb, 2021 - 1 Days (Priyanka (880099))\", \"Worker\": \"Priyanks (880099)\", \"Request Type\": \"Time Off Request\", \"Time Off/Absence Table\": \"IND Sick/Casual Time Off\", \"Type\": \"Sick/Casual Leave\", \"Entered On\": 1612310400000, \"Approval Date\": 1612310400000, \"Time Off Date\": 1612137600000, \"Approved\": 1, \"Unit of Time\": \"Days\" }]"
json_data = json.loads(json_string)

from jsonpath_ng.ext import parser
query = [x.value for x in parser.parse('$[?(@.Worker =~ ".*880099.*")]').find(json_data)]
print(json.dumps(query))
```